# $regex and $text together within $or

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query both text search and regex inside a `$or` in mongo but its throws the following error

```
Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR - other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well.
```

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
query.$or = [
    { 'vehicle.name': { $regex: searchQuery, $options: 'i' } },
    {
        $text: {
          $search: search,
          $caseSensitive: false,
        }
     }
];
```

Also I can't index `vehicle.name` since it would break text searches at other places that's why I want to find it only in current controller using regex

Answer (score 0):

Create a regular index on `vehicle.name`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27695863)

Comment: What question do you think is being asked?